# Implementing Do keyword in a compiler

Tags: programming-languages, compilers, syntax

I'm writting a compiler implementation for a language that you can see defined [here](http://lara.epfl.ch/w/cc16:tool). I having problems designing how the do keyword should be handled. You can find the code I'm referring to in [here](https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/92679781/Evaluator.scala).

Let me delve a little bit into the problem. According to the documentation:

> The do keyword is used to call an expression (normally, a method call)
>   just for its side-effect, and discards the result.

Now according to the list of possible expressions in the file I referred to before:

```
IntLit(value) 
StringLit(value)
True()
False() 
And(lhs, rhs) 
Or(lhs, rhs)  
Plus(lhs, rhs) 
Minus(lhs, rhs) 
Times(lhs, rhs) 
Div(lhs, rhs) 
LessThan(lhs, rhs) 
Not(expr)
Equals(lhs, rhs)  
ArrayRead(arr, index) 
ArrayLength(arr) 
MethodCall(obj, meth, args)
Variable(Identifier(name))
New(tpe)      
This()
NewIntArray(size)
```

I want to figure out first in which cases should do act. Clearly, it should act with MethodCall as it provides a result but also with expressions that contain operators (And,Or,Plus,Minus,Times,Div,LessThan,Not,Equals,...). What would be the complete list of cases I should consider?

My second question is how can I implement Do behaviour for MethodCall, that is, not getting the result but getting the side effects.

Comment: The problem statement seems to specify that `do` can wrap around *any* expression.

Comment: Just implement `do exp` as you would do for `x = exp` but don't store the result in variable `x`.

Comment: @Raphael certainly it can wrap around any expression so my solution would have a generic case for those that do not need special treatment

Comment: @chi you mean like in the line     case Assign(id, expr) => ectx.setVariable(id.value, evalExpr(expr))?

Comment: @chi So maybe just evalExpr(expr) would work?

Comment: Try e.g. `... => evalExpr(expr); ()` which calls the evaluator, discards its result and returns `(): Unit` anyway. I don't know Scala enough to say if there's a better (more idiomatic) way.

Comment: @chi Make this an answer?

Comment: @YuvalFilmus Done, even if this now looks as a programming question/answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The general idea is that `do ( expression )` is a statement that evaluates any expression and throws away the result.

A first attempt could be

```
  def evalExpr(e: ExprTree)(implicit ectx: EvaluationContext): Value =
    // ...

  def evalStatement(stmt: StatTree)(implicit ectx: EvaluationContext): Unit =
    stmt match {
      // ...
      case DoExpr(expr) => 
        evalExpr(expr)
    }
  }
```

but in this way, we return a `Value` and not a `Unit`, so the compiler raises a type error. We can fix that by using

```
      case DoExpr(expr) => 
        evalExpr(expr)
        ()  // the Unit value
```